# Java - Atmosphere long polling sends only first message

Tags: java, spring-boot, long-polling, atmosphere

I'm trying to implement a notification mechanism where a client connects to the server and is receiving updates.

Each user connects to a service end point like this

```
@ManagedService(path = "/chat/{userId}")
```

When they connect, they are registered in the broadcaster like this

```
    @Ready
    public void onReady(final AtmosphereResource resource) {
        Broadcaster broadcaster = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(userId,true);
        broadcaster.addAtmosphereResource(resource);
    }
```

When i want to send a message from a REST end point for example, i do it like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ws2/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        Broadcaster broadcaster = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(userId,true);
        broadcaster.broadcast(new Message(userId, "User id : "));
    }
```

It works very well when i'm using the **web-socket** implementation.
When i change to **long-polling** and calling this REST method, only the first message is sent, others are ignored with no errors or logs of any kind.
What can i do in this case?